# strtok adding an extra line?

Tags: c, strtok

I am having trouble reading and a splitting up a multiline user input with the strtok function. I need to split it up by the spaces in between however, I think the strtok keeps adding an extra line?

For example:

A user would paste a block of text like:

324 A 1 D F

829 Z 3 3 F G

1234 C 3 F G

234 D 2 3

When I printed the output of the tokens, it showed me:

324 A 1 D F

829 Z 3 3 F G

1234 C 3 F G

<--- where random new line generates after pressing enter --->

234 D 2 3 . <-- only shows up after the random line generates..

---

Lines 1 to 3, printed into the console right after I pasted the block in the console. 
After pressing enter, it makes a new line inbetween and finally prints the last line. Then I have to press enter again for the program to end.

This is my code:

```
int main(void) {
char input[256];
int done = 1;
while (done!=0){
        fgets(input,256,stdin);
        char* t;
        printf("\n");

        t=strtok(input, " \n");

        if (*t == '\n'){
            done = 0;
        } else{
            while (t!= NULL){
                printf("%s " ,t);
                t = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger, and I believe the problem will become obvious

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for the advice. I went through the code using GDB online and it says I have a segmentation fault with exit code 139. I googled around and it said it's probably because I'm trying to access an invalid memory (or ran out) or my program is running infinitely. Is it cause my loop condition is wrong? I tried switching up the t pointers, but it's still doing the same thing :(

Comment: I was referring to the line of code where you told it to print an extra newline

Answer (score 1):

First rule of IO operations: *never* assume they succeed.

1. Unchecked result from `fgets`.
2. If you're `strok` stops (and terminates on) *either* a space or a newline, how do you ever expect `*t` to point to a newline. Therefore `done = 0;` will *never* hit. Therefore you jump into failed `fgets` calls you never check, etc.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char input[256];

    // check for failure to read, on a line with newline first
    while (fgets(input, 256, stdin) != NULL && *input != '\n')
    {
        char *t = strtok(input, " \n");
        while (t != NULL) 
        {
            printf("%s ", t);
            t = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
324 A 1 D F
829 Z 3 3 F G
1234 C 3 F G
234 D 2 3
```

**Output**

```
324 A 1 D F 
829 Z 3 3 F G 
1234 C 3 F G 
234 D 2 3
```

[**See it live on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/j3SoiN)